# VBS / iMacros - What is error code -911

Tags: firefox, vbscript, wsh, imacros

What is this error code?

The link `-100...-999 (sMacroError)` on [this page](http://wiki.imacros.net/Error-Codes)  just reloads the `SAME PAGE` again.  Great.

I get this error when I execute this .vbs file:

```
Option Explicit
Dim iim1, iret

'initialize iMacros instance
set iim1 = CreateObject ("iMacros")
iret = iim1.iimInit("-fx", false)

do while not iret < 1
iret = iim1.iimPlay("Load CNN Comments",30)
loop

' tell user we're done
msgbox "End." &iret

' exit iMacros instance and quit script
Wscript.Quit()
```

Here is "Load CNN Comments"

```
VERSION BUILD=6650406 RECORDER=FX
TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:Load<SP>next<SP>25
WAIT SECONDS=#DOWNLOADCOMPLETE#
```

I run this with a CNN.COM article open in Firefox. The idea is that the "load next 25" comments will be selected (automatically by the macro) until all the comments are loaded on the page. It's only executing once, and returning `error code -911`.

Software:
iMacros for Firefox 6.6.5.0; iMacros 6.90; Firefox 3.6.3; Windows XP Pro SP3 w/all updates.